# What languages are used in Stack Overflow's 404 polygot?

Tags: programming-languages, polyglot

Currently, when a user here gets a 404, they see the following image:

[image: polygot-404.png]

Which represents the text:

```
# define v putchar
#   define print(x) main(){v(4+v(v(52)-4));return 0;}/*
#>+++++++4+[>++++++<-]> ++++.----.++++.*/
print(202*2);exit();
#define/*>.@*/exit()
```

This looks suspiciously *polyglottish*. Which languages does this do something interesting in?

---

Side thought: Is it just me, or did I find a bug in Prettify?

Comment: Flag for alt.se.prog; Possible duplicate of two meta questions: [What's the joke in the Stack Overflow 404 page code?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28625/whats-the-joke-in-the-stack-overflow-404-page-code)" and "[Amusing 404 "Page Not Found" Images for Trilogy sites?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27112/amusing-404-page-not-found-images-for-trilogy-sites)".

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27112/amusing-404-page-not-found-images-for-trilogy-sites

Comment: Older thread, more detailed: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252184/whats-the-joke-in-the-stack-overflow-404-page-code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Line 4 with the `print(202*2)` is valid in any number of scripting languages like Perl, Ruby, ECMAScript (provided a suitable implementation of a `print` function) and probably Python.

Line 2 is there to make line 4 valid in C and Objective-C, maybe also C++ and Objective-C++.

Line 3 contains some Brainfuck, but there seems to be something else there.

I have no idea what line 1 with the `v` is for. Why not just call `putchar` directly in line 2? So, I suspect that there's another language that is somehow made valid through this line. (At first I thought about Whitespace, but there's not enough whitespace in there to be a valid Whitespace program.)

And line 5 obviously also contains some code in some highly compressed language. Maybe something in the APL family (J, K, ...) or Golfscript?

Comment: Befunge! That's what I was missing.

Answer (score 9):

It is `C` and `brainf**k`. They both print `404`.

Comment: The first part of the line with the Brainfuck is something else.

Comment: @ohmantics: Actually, there are (at least) two lines with (important) Brainfuck on them. (Technically line 2 has some, but its just the `+` and the `-` and those obviously cancel each-other out.) At least, I *think* line 5 is important somehow...

Comment: In fact, I'm also inclined to guess that the strange use of spaces/tabs might also be Whitespace.

Comment: @ohmantics: Unfortunately, the distinction between spaces and tabs is not preserved very well by the rasterization + OCR process

Comment: The loops on the third line seem to serve no purpose.

Comment: @ohmantics: I think it's the standard "build a constant by multiplying" trick, actually. (And it's just one loop.)

Comment: Those Brainfuck loops are part of the Befunge version.

Comment: -1 it's more than C and brainf***. It's also valid in many scripting languages like Perl.